# Where are the arguments to the jQueryUI Dialog submit handler coming from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Take a look at the following code:

```
  this.dialog({
                    width: 500,
                    height: 260,
                    title: "Setup database",
                    content: $("<form>").append(table),
                    buttons: {
                        submit: function(_alert, dialog) {
                            dialog.find("form").each(function() {
                                var arr = $(this).serializeArray();
                                var data = {
                                    mysql: true
                                };
                                var empty = false;
                                $(this).find("input").removeClass("error");
                                for (var k in arr) {
                                    if ($.trim(arr[k].value) !== "") {
                                        data[arr[k].name] = arr[k].value;
                                    } else {
                                        empty = true;
                                        $(this).find("input[name='" + arr[k].name + "']").each(function() {
                                            $(this).addClass("error");
                                        });
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (!empty) {
                                    self.ajax({
                                        url: url,
                                        data: data
                                    }, function(result) {
                                        callback(result);
                                    }, function() {
                                        self.mysql(url, callback, _db_name, _db_user, _db_pass, is_dialog);
                                    });
                                }
                                _alert.remove();
                                if($.isFunction(callback_submit)) {
                                    callback_submit();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

There are two parameters passed into the anonymous function that is supposed to trigger when the button "submit" is clicked. But I have no idea where these parameters are supposed to come from. Can someone explain? Is this related to passing parameters to an anonymous function in Javascript in general?

Comment: Does this code actually work? Can you reduce it to a working example and build a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you get any argument passed to you when a button event callback is fired on jquery-ui dialog box

http://jsfiddle.net/3d7QC/1577/

```
buttons: {
    "I've read and understand this": function() {
        console.log(arguments);
        // look at your console
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
```

Only argument you get passed through to you is the customary jQuery event object.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument `_alert` is the JS event object that is passed to every event handler in JavaScript. This is not specific to jQuery. [javascript.info explains this as follows](http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object):

> W3C way
>
> Browsers which follow W3C standards always pass the event object as
>   the first argument for the handler.
>
> For instance:
>
> ```
> element.onclick = function(event) {
>  // process data from event
> }
> ```

In the [jQueryUI API reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons) they confirm that i

> Specifies which buttons should be displayed on the dialog. The context
>   of the callback is the dialog element; if you need access to the
>   button, it is available as the target of the event object.

I [illustrated this in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simbabque/x7c9M/). Not sure what the second argument (`dialog` in your case) does, though. It's not passed in my example code.

Comment: Second arg should be undefined, not applicable.

Comment: In the OP's code there is a second argument `dialog` which is used in the event handler. It has to come from somewhere unless it's a variable from further up the current scope.

Comment: Right, what I should have said is by default, jQueryUI Dialog only passes back the event object. You're right, it has to be further up the scope. Seems to be passing in an already stored instance of the dialog, it looks like.

Comment: Actually no. It would be overwritten by the `function(foo, bar)` definition and in the smaller scope still be `undefined`. See my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/simbabque/x7c9M/1/.

Comment: Ah indeed, you'd need to remove it from the definition if you intend to use an external var with the same name. Suggests that the internals of the handler are broken.

Answer (score 0):

There should only be one parameter passed to submit, which is the event object of the button itself, when clicked. So the context set is the submit button, if you need to access the dialog and modify it, you can do so by accessing the event.target property.

```
  this.dialog({
  buttons: {
      submit: function(event) {
         $(event).dialog('close'); //is the same as...
         $(this).dialog('close');
      }
   });
```